# Bootsrap 3: bootstrap-select and input-group-addon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two input-groups put into form-groups. The first one has three group addons and everything looks right. The second one with bootstrap-select has two addons, one on the left, second on the right, and this is causing bootstrap-select having rounded corners, although it is placed between two addons. Moreover if I leave there just one addon it looks fine.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group" id="dateOfBirthDiv">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            @Html.Label("Data urodzenia")
        </span>
        @Html.TextBox("dateOfBirth", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="min-width: 42px;">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            @Html.Label("Płeć")
        </span>
        @Html.DropDownList("patientSex", new SelectList(SelectListHelpers.sexSelectListHelper, "Value", "Text"), "-- wybierz --", new { @class = "selectpicker form-control" })
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="min-width: 42px;">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code is Razor syntax but I think everybody will understand that DropDownList is changed to `<select>`. Then bootstrap-select change it in its way.

I think it can be like that because  is hidden by bootstrap-select but why it is working with one addon?
Has anybody meet similar problems?

[image: View]

Comment: What browser is this in? [The docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) say `Avoid using <select> elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers.`. Also I'm guessing you are using some sort of select box plugin to give it extra functionality. Have you tried removing that and seeing what happens, then you cna see if it is a general issue or just due to a plugin.

Comment: Are you able to recreate this problem on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/) ? It tough to say what is going on here, without inspecting it in DevTools in a browser

Comment: It is bootstrap-select failure. It puts `<button>` in `<div>`. The `<div>` has `form-control` class but its color is transparent and `<button>` has no `form-control` class that is responsible for `border-radius` managment. Even if I update `form-control` class  `<button>` with jQuery the button is the first element in `<div>` so it has rounded corners on the left side and square on the right :) solution was `$('#patientSex').next('div.bootstrap-select').children('button.dropdown-toggle').css('border-radius', '0px');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bootstrap-select failure. It puts `<button>` in `<div>`. The `<div>` has `form-control` class but its color is transparent and `<button>` has no `form-control` class that is responsible for `border-radius` managment. Even if I add `form-control` class to `<button>` with jQuery the button is the first element in `<div>` so it has rounded corners on the left side and square on the right :) solution is `$('#patientSex').next('div.bootstrap-select').children('button.dropdown-toggle').css('border-radius', '0px');`.

Answer (score 1):

My symilar code works. You should try remome form-group block or add some empty select element next to your select and remove it via js on document ready.

My code:

```
<div class="container"><div class="col-md-2">
<div class="input-group"><a href="keyboard-new"><span class="btn btn-primary">Nowy</span></a></div></div>           
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group"> 
    <span class="input-group-addon">
          lalalalala
        </span>
    <select id="searchcolumn" class="form-control">
    <option value="NAZWA">Nazwa</option>
    </select> 
     <span class="input-group-addon">
          lalalalala
        </span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

looks correct:[image: generated page]